# Design pattern for Java Spring data JPA projects

Tags: java, spring-boot, design-patterns, spring-data-jpa, microservices

This is my current project  design
Controller-> service -> Repository

I am trying to understand :

1. What layer(Name) i can create between Controller-> service  if in
   case i need to have layer which can be composition of services.
2. What layer I can create between service -> Repository .
3. If i am having Repository Layer can i also keep DAO layer.

Many Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The service layer is the thing you need to use when manipulating with data retrieved from db. So you do not need to create extra-layers between controller-service-repository. The main idea is to use repository for db operations, service for data manipulation + additional logic, controller for creating api. Or there is an approach with additional api layer where you create api interfaces then controller implements them and then service(logic) and repository(sql)

Comment: Thanks its useful . Apart from these  3 layers (Controller(interface)-> Service-> Repository in micro service  Can we add any other layer  for any other use case.

Comment: I actually disagree with this. Controllers are an essential part of the Spring framework - thus this should be part of the infra/core level. Now after this there must be some business layer that will hold business logic and they should call service classes that manipulate and process the data. Entities and Repositories should not be there directly where business logic is written else it will be challenging to accommodate future changes.